# How can I get difference using preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

```
<?php
$format='(212) ### ### ##';
$phone='(212) 121 333 45';
$format=str_replace('(','\(',$format);
$format=str_replace(')','\)',$format);
$format=str_replace('.','\.',$format);
$format=str_replace('#','[0-9]',$format);
$pattern="/^".$format."$/";
//pattern->  /^\(212\) [0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]$/
if (preg_match($pattern,$phone)) echo 'true'; else echo 'false';
?>
```

input (212) 121 333 45
I want result as; 1213345

It's success but this is only check. I want matched chars same time.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you trying to validate a given user input according a predefined format? Or are you trying to remove certain parts from the original string? Please clarify.

Comment: format=`(212) ### ### ##` user input=`(212) 121 333 45` Firstly I validate user input, then I want just numbers except pattern numbers. So I want 12134345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a little "regex construction" work:

```
$format='(212) ### ### ##';
$phone='(212) 121 333 45';

// Quote any characters such as ( in the format so they match the input literally
// $regex == \(212\) ### ### ##
$regex = preg_quote($format, '/');

// Then surround any groups of #s with parens, making them capturing groups
// $regex == \(212\) (###) (###) (##)
$regex = preg_replace('/#+/', '(\0)', $regex);

// Finally, replace the placeholder # with \d and surround with slashes
// $regex == /\(212\) (\d\d\d) (\d\d\d) (\d\d)/
$regex = '/'.str_replace('#', '\d', $regex).'/';
```

Now we 're ready to roll:

```
if (preg_match($regex, $phone, $matches)) {
    echo "Matched: ".implode('', array_slice($matches, 1));
}
else {
    echo "No match";
}
```

The construct `array_slice($matches, 1)` creates an array of the contents of each capturing group, so with the example input it would result in the array `['121', '333', '45']`. `implode` joins these bits together, producing `12133345`.

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/Uhna2i)**.